# background of unselected states in AnyCharts AnyMap

Tags: anychart

By default, unselected states in the Anycharts Anymap are colored as white, and aren't affected by the anychart.scales color definitions as far as I can determine.

I am using

```
series.colorScale(anychart.scales.linearColor('#002626', '#027575'));
```

and when I am rendering a map that intentionally only shows one state, it shows that one state as the high color, but shows all the unset states as white.

Is there a way to set that color as well, preferably with an alpha channel?

Comment: Can you please send a playground sample that would reflect your problem? In this sample, you can see that selected states are grey and unselected ones take the colorScale colors: https://playground.anychart.com/zl6BSda2

Comment: I found it. The difference is I had to use = anychart.scales.ordinalColor(); 

linearColor only accepts basic solid colors, but ordinalColor accepts rgba..  
so instead of   

var colorScale = anychart.scales.linearColor(['#B2DFDB', '#004D40']);   

I can use     

var colorScale = anychart.scales.ordinalColor();
colorScale.colors(['rgba(25,24,25,0.2)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)']);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use transparent colors for your states, you need to use `anychart.scales.ordinalColor();` instead of `anychart.scales.linearColor();`

example:

```
 var colorScale = anychart.scales.ordinalColor();
 colorScale.colors(['rgba(0,0,0,0.2)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)']);
```

Will run from 80% transparent black to 10% transparent black;